# Examples of Abelian groups with certain non-terminating descreasing chains

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

**Q1.** What are some examples of Abelian groups containing
 a chain of strictly decreasing subgroups $\{G_n\}_{n\in\mathbb Z} $  (i.e. $G_{n+1}<G_n$ and $G_{n+1}\not=G_n$ ) such that

i)$\cup_n G_n=G \text{ and } \cap_n G_n=1$ (non-Artinian covering )

ii)
$\sup\{\text{order}(\frac{G_n}{G_{n+1}})\: n\in\mathbb Z\}<\infty$ (order of quotient groups are controlled).

**Q2.** In particular, does additive group of reals $(\mathbb R,+)$ contain such a chain?

Comment: I'm confused. Is this chain supposed to look like $G=G_0\supset G_1\supset\cdots$? Because if so then the condition $\cup_n G_n$ is superfluous.

Comment: @AlexMathers: The chain is ordered by integers.

Comment: to add up to $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many examples.  For a particularly simple one, let $(A_k)_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}$ be any sequence of nontrivial abelian groups of bounded order, let $G=\bigoplus_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}A_k$, and let $G_n=\bigoplus_{k\geq n}A_k$.  Or you could let $G$ be the subgroup of $\prod_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}A_k$ consisting of elements whose support is bounded below, and $G_n=\prod_{k\geq n} A_k$.

For another sort of example, let $p$ be a prime number and take $G=\mathbb{Z}[1/p]$, with $G_n=p^n\mathbb{Z}$.  Variations on this example include $G=\mathbb{Q}$ with $G_n=p^n\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$, or $G=\mathbb{Q}_p$ with $G_n=p^n\mathbb{Z}_p$.  Since $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ as a group (they are both just $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$), this answers your second question.

Comment: By $\mathbb{Z} [1/p]$ you mean the p-adic numbers?is that right?

Comment: No, I mean the subring of $\mathbb{Q}$ generated by $1/p$.  The $p$-adic integers is $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant. I come from a different field and didn't get terminology right

Answer (score 2):

For each $k\in {\bf Z}$, choose your favourite finite abelian group $G_k$ of order at most $N$ (where $N$ is your favourite natural number greater than $1$). Then the set of all sequences $(g_k)_k$ with $g_k\in G_k$ and all but finitely many $g_k= e_{G_k}$ is an example.

Alternately, take all sequences such that eventually $g_k=e_{G_k}$.

Moreover, you can take any intermediate groups between the two.

Comment: These aren't all the examples, because you can have nontrivial extensions between the levels of the filtration.

Comment: No, see the second paragraph of my answer for some examples.

Comment: @EricWofsey: I see, you're right. For some reason I thought that non-split extensions are nonabelian.